# How to query for models with specific parent (not any ancestor) in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The [docs says](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Ancestor_Queries) that `ancestor` will apply a filter of given ancestor being somewhere in the ancestry tree.

> You can filter your datastore queries to a specified ancestor, so that results contain only   entities containing that ancestor. In other words, all of the results will have the **ancestor as their parent, or parent's parent**, or etc. Passing None as a parameter does not query for entities without ancestors and will return errors.

Can I somehow filter on one level, immediate ancestor relationship so that a query will provide models having specific parent? Or must I store parent relationship in a `ReferenceProperty` and filter on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: querying for ancestor will get all parents, not only the direct one. To get the direct parent only, you must store it in a property (can be a ReferenceProperty or you can just store an encoded key in a StringProperty), then query for it.

Comment: Or you could store 'depth' as a property, and query on ancestor and depth.